# Creating our own A2DP profile using java

Tags: java, bluetooth, profile, a2dp

Many of us have used bluetooth headset/earphones or alike devices having in-built programmed A2DP (advanced audio directing profile) so that they can recieve streaming audio  from a standard device.

But I wanted to design (code and implement) my own bluetooth A2DP profile using java which can be installed on a mobile device so that very device can recieve and ouput streaming audio recieved from another device.

For instance: My laptop has a bluetooth stack as well as my cellphone has.
As an ordinary cellphone it does not have a A2DP profile
But what if my cellphone is connected to an amplifier and I want to dorect my laptop's audio to that amplifier wirelessly.

Proposition: if I design a installable java based (java, because its widely accepted as mobile device's supportive language) A2DP bluetooth profile then my cellphone can be used as a bluetooth based audio reciever.

But the main question is how and from where to start off?

Comment: have you found something since? I have the same intent and beyond. I want to be client and server for hfp, a2dp and avrcp, and funnel the hfp adio into the a2dp. I suspect having to read/write all bytes of redo the whole profiles on top of l2cap (judging by diagrams alone).

Answer (score -2):

why do not you use your Bluetooth Headset instead.This ways you can connect your bluetooth device to Amplifier and it can stream audio from both your cell as well as laptop.

Comment: A headset is a trivial device without a way to hook to some amplifier.
Besides, the question remains as to how to do the A2DP impl on android.